# How to get GitLab commits of a file using python gitlab module?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

We are trying to get the commits of each file in a Gitlab repository. We are using the Python Gitlab module. We could get the commits of a repository but couldn't get the commits of individual files in the repository. Can someone help us with this?

Answer (score 4):

The commit history of a single file is not exposed through the GitLab API directly. Therefore, there is no direct functionality for this in the python-gitlab `gitlab` module.

However, you can obtain, effectively, the same information by using available APIs. Specifically, you can either use the repository [commits API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits) and diff APIs or the files [blame API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-blame-from-repository).

### Using the commits API

For example, using the commits API, you can list all commits and their diffs, then associate file changes for each commit.

```py
import gitlab
from collections import defaultdict
TOKEN = 'Your API Token'
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.example.com', private_token=TOKEN)

project = gl.projects.get(1234)
commits = project.commits.list(all=True)

# file paths and a list of commits which create/modify/delete the file
file_map = defaultdict(list)

for c in commits:
    diff = c.diff()
    files_changed = set()
    for change in diff:
        files_changed.add(change['old_path'])
        files_changed.add(change['new_path'])
    for path in files_changed:
        file_map[path].append(c)

#  show list of commits which modified README.md
print(file_map['README.md'])
```

### Using the blame API

Using the commits API requires obtaining the diff for every commit, which can take a long time on large repositories.

If you're only interested in the commits which change a single file, traversing the blame tree can be more efficient. However, note that you may also miss commits (for example, commits in other branches or diverged trees) using this method.

```py
def search_blame(project, filename, base_ref=None):
    if base_ref is None:
        base_ref = project.default_branch
    commits = set()
    refs_to_check = [base_ref,]
    seen = set()
    while refs_to_check:
        ref = refs_to_check.pop()
        if ref in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(ref)
        blame = project.files.blame(filename, ref)
        for change in blame:
            commit_id = change['commit']['id']
            if commit_id not in seen:
                refs_to_check.append(commit_id)
                refs_to_check.extend(change['commit']['parent_ids'])
                for c in change['commit']['parent_ids']:
                    commits.add(c)
            commits.add(commit_id)
    return commits

# show commits in blame tree for README.md
# only includes commits in the default branch
print(search_blame(project, 'README.md'))
```